# Half of my video rendered and red line middle of the display

Tags: rendering

[image]There is no problem in rendered image. When i combine images and make video. So the problem begins when i rendered the animation and it shows up like this. Can somebody explain me why this is happening..?
(i cropped the image because of the size)